# What is the meaning of "weltfremd"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Examples (two from this site):

- Er ist komisch eher *weltfremd*.
- Man belächelte seinen Vorschlag als *weltfremd*.
- Purismus aus Prinzip ist *weltfremd*

What is the meaning?

Dictionaries give varied translations - such as "absurd", "sheltered", "unworldly" - some of which are no less confusing. I suspect that "naive" could be closest to the reality (no pun intended).

Comment: This is one of those German words that are difficult to translate to English. "weltfremd" is the opposite of being grounded in reality.

Comment: In part, the definition is in the word itself. *Welt*="world", *fremd*="strange/foreign/external". This looks like a good time to use a usage database; see [quotes from Die ZEIT](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=zeit&q=weltfremd).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of a good single-word translation, but the meaning clearly is

> decoupled from reality

In the best case it means for a proposal *a bit too theoretical to work* (which may acknowledge some positive aspect covered) in the worst case *this ignores some obvious facts* (and could be meant as an insult).

Comment: funnily enough, the person who called someone else "weltfremd" said that because they (the one speaking) were insisting COVID was over... while coughing out all their lungs.

Comment: That's a wrong use of that expession anyway. Should be *schizophren*.

Answer (score 3):

*Weltfremd* means it comes right from the ivory tower. It may be sound but it's not applicable in the real word. That's the difference to *naive* which means that there hasn't been put too much thought into it.

*Weltfremd* is often used when human factors or the resources at hand of the people who have to implement it are not considered.

A *weltfremd* person is someone who lives in their very own ivory tower.